# Plotly: How to format numeric yaxis and hover text?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a python plotly graph with numeric yaxis, it automatically formats the yaxis numbers to 'k' scale and and when hovering the point, shows values like `115.277258k.

How can I change the scale to display 100,000 instead of `100k` and also format the hovering text to show `115,2772.58` instead of `115.277258k`?

[plotly graph example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yLap.jpg)

[image]

Currently plotting multiple subplots using a loop.

```
for i in range(1, allcities.size + 1):
    for col in ['total_inflow', 'total_outflow', 'total_withdraw', 'total_account']:
        plot_data = hist[hist['city_id'] == allcities[i - 1]]
        plot_data = plot_data.merge(datelist, on='balance_date', how='right')
        fig.append_trace({'x': plot_data['balance_date'],
                          'y': round(plot_data[col], 2),
                          'type': 'scatter',
                          'mode': 'lines', 
                          'line': dict(color=line_colors[col]),
                          'showlegend': False,
                          'name': line_legends[col]
                          }, i + 1, 1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the hovertemplate for `go.Scatter()` like this:

```
hovertemplate = 'y:%{y:20,.2f}'
```

And you can edit the tick labels using `update_layout(yaxis=dict())` like this:

```
yaxis=dict(tickformat="20,.2f")
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x**6, y=x**4,
                                mode='lines+markers',
                                hovertemplate = '<i>y</i>:%{y:20,.2f}'+ '<br><b>x</b>: %{x}<br>',

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(tickformat="20,.2f"),
                  xaxis=dict(tickformat="20,.2f", tickangle = 0))


fig.show()
```